# How to check if a ZipArchiveEntry in .NET 4.5 is corrupt

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, zip, .net-4.5

I'm using the new [ZipArchive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) and [ZipArchiveEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchiveentry.aspx) classes of .NET 4.5 to extract files from a Zip package.

That's basically whats happening:

```
try {
    using (var archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
        {
            // Check if file should be extracted
            ...

            entry.ExtractToFile(@"C:\Test\" + entry.FullName, true)
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unzipping error: " + ex.Message);
}
```

When I try to unzip this file with the standard Windows Explorer "Extract All..." command or with 7zip I always get an error (as expected because I made the file corrupt for testing purposes), but when I try the code no exception is thrown and all files are getting unzipped.

According to the [Microsoft MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh485718.aspx) an `InvalidDataException` should be thrown.

> **ZipFileExtensions.ExtractToDirectory**
>
> *InvalidDataException*
>
> The entry is missing from the archive or is corrupt and cannot be
>   read.
>   -or- The entry has been compressed by using a compression method that is not supported.

What am I doing wrong? Or how can I check if a file in this package is corrupt?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you "made the file corrupt" for us?

Comment: I opend the zip file in a hex editor and changed 4 bytes to a random value. When extracting it with external tools I get something like "file test.exe couldn't be extracted because it's corrupt"

Comment: Does the successfully (without error) extracted file contain corruption after you export it?

Comment: On a side note, I would use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) for your `entry.ExtractToFile(@"C:\Test\" + entry.FullName, true)` line.

Comment: The extracted file is unusable, when I extract it with the .NET 4.5 implementation. I've now switched back to [DotNetZip](https://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) and everything works as expected (exception is thrown). But I would like a solution without an external library better.

Comment: it seems like the .NET implementation is not doing the checksum on the file; but DotNetZip, 7Zip, et al are.